# Can't set IsSelected property for a ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to set the IsSelected for a ComboBoxItem it throws `Set property 'IsSelected' threw an exception`. What should I do?

Here's the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="rowsPerPageCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="120" SelectionChanged="rowsPerPageCombo_SelectionChanged" Background="White">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page10" Content="10" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page20" Content="20"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page30" Content="30"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page40" Content="40"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page50" Content="50"/>
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Your XAML is fine. you need to post your code behind related combobox. so that we can able to find issues. you put break point in your rowsPerPageCombo_SelectionChanged and debug

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `SelectedIndex` property to 0 instead of setting the selected item on the `ComboBoxItem` element

```
<ComboBox x:Name="rowsPerPageCombo" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="120" SelectionChanged="rowsPerPageCombo_SelectionChanged" Background="White">
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page10" Content="10" />
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page20" Content="20"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page30" Content="30"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page40" Content="40"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Page50" Content="50"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I tried that too. It throws: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Comment: Can you post some of the C# code you're using with this ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say where your error is without having seen your code but make sure that the window has been loaded before yoy try to anything in the SelectionChanged event handler. You could return immediately if the IsLoaded property returns false:

```
private void rowsPerPageCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsLoaded)
        return;

    //your code...
}
```

If you remove `SelectionChanged="rowsPerPageCombo_SelectionChanged"` and don't handle the SelectionChanged event you will probably get rid of the exception. Otherwise it is related to something else in your code.